# How the Heisenberg principle affects the dispersion of a wave in various wavelengths?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, dispersion

I have read "when things happen too fast", unavoidably, a wave is dispersed to many wavelengths and that the uncertainty principle is behind this.

Do you think that this statement is true? If yes, how is explained this connection?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where?

Comment: The uncertainty principle is a general result from Fourier analysis. Any time you have a (say linear) propagating wave with support over a short interval (e.g. a component of a longer complicated signal), it necessarily includes components from a broad frequency range, each of which typically propagates at a different speed.  Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: I would rather think that what you mean is more related to dispersion (which may or may not occur, depending on the nature of the underlying differential equation) and that Heisenberg principle has nothing to do there. But I agree with fs137 that being more specific would help.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two concepts are analogous, but not equivalent. Dispersion is a classical wave phenomenon that exists for some differential equations describing wave propatation, but not for others (those describing soliton wave propagation, for example) For linear classical wave propagation Fourier analysis relates dispersion and duration via a relation that is similar to the Heisenberg uncertainty relation.

The Heisenberg uncertainty relation is associated with quantum mechanics. Although quantum mechanics is described by the Schrodinger wave equation, the waves here are not classical waves, but probability waves. The uncertainty relation has Planck's constant which has nothing to do with classical Fourier analysis. Hence they are not the same.

Comment: One persnickety remark: the *general* 'uncertainty principle' of Fourier analysis is different from the 'Heisenberg uncertainty principle'. The fact that momentum and position can't be measured simultaneously follows from the fact that a function and its fourier transform can't simultaneously have compact support.

Comment: Being even more persnickety: the uncertainty relation involves Planck's constant in QM ($h/(4\pi)$) and $1/(4\pi)$ in Fourier analysis because the Fourier transform is "defined" differently, but the maths behind are exactly the same.

Comment: @claude chuber: I posted my earlier comment because  I think it's common for physicists to automatically assume that any reference to the 'uncertainty principle' must involve quantum mechanics. At a purely mathematical level, the phenomenon is relevant to the dispersion of localized wave packets of any field that doesn't have a unique (or finite set of) wave speed(s).

Comment: @fs137 : I was actually addressing Lewis Miller claim "The uncertainty relation has Planck's constant which has nothing to do with classical Fourier analysis. Hence they are not the same" which I find inaccurate.

Comment: @Claudechuber Planck's constant could be a different value and the uncertainty principle and QM would be different, yet the relation between duration and dispersion for classical waves would be unchanged. It is not unusual for two different physical phenomena to be described by the same mathematics.

Comment: @Lewis Miller  Plank's constant could very well be different, if only you would change its constitutive units J and s. But the uncertainty principle and QM would still remain the same.